# Best way to test/debug javascript mappers/policies in Keycloak

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, jboss-tools, keycloak-services

I am new to Keycloak and have been trying to setup javascript based authz policies and client mappers. I was wondering what is the best way to debug such mappers or policies.

Right now, if there are any errors within the script I can only find out it in the server logs, but is there a way where we can use something like alert or console.log; in both cases the server logs mentions:

```
Caused by: <eval>:18 ReferenceError: "alert" is not defined
Caused by: <eval>:18 ReferenceError: "console" is not defined
```

It will be really helpful if when the script runs , if i can atleast log the values of properties or attributes to check whats going on

Comment: Found the answer to this, keycloak uses Nashorn engine for js and we can use print() to print/logs the values in keycloak console

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
print("something");
```

you will see it in server logs

Comment: I wish there is a way to debug like regular java scripts, I need to inspect objects. When I pass headers in auth requests they are empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can start KeyCloak with Debug-Option, e.g. with the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting KeyCloak"
sh ./keycloak-4.7.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh --debug 6666
```

I used this to debug my java-mappers and java-provider. Perhaps it can also help for javascript.